# How to get PNG base64 encoded from CGImageRef?

Tags: objective-c, macos, png, base64, cgimageref

i have CGImageRef object (var quartzImage). How convert this object to format PNG data for web:
"data:image/png;base64,"+ base64 data image

my code:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    NSLog(@"%@",quartzImage);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
[image lockFocus];
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithFocusedViewRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
[image unlockFocus];
NSData *imageData = [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];;
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you already have a `CGImageRef` (with name `quartzImage` in your code) then you do not need to create an `NSImage`. Create a `NSBitmapImageRep` directly. And you should in no case use the `lockFocus` method. This is good for images that shall be depicted to the screen. And therefore `lockFocus` usually creates images with a resolution of 72 dpi and 144 dpi for Retina screens. Or do you want to create images for the web with the properties of your screen? Try this:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:quartzImage];
NSData *repData = [bitmapRep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType] properties:nil];
NSString *base64String = [repData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

This `base64`… method is not available before OS X 10.9. In that case you should use `base64Encoding`